# Generators of difference of two poisson processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Assume $X_1(t)$, $X_2(t)$ are two poisson processes with parameters $\rho_1$, $\rho_2$ accordingly. Suppose $Z(t)=X_1(t)=X_1(t)-X_2(t)$. At first I'm interest in knowing generators of the process $Z(t)$ . Now if $\rho_1>\rho_2$, define $T=\inf\{t:Z(t)=1\}$ . What will be $E(t)$? And at the end I need $Var(T)$. Thank you for your helps.

Comment: And... what did you try to solve any of these questions, which similar problems can you solve, which aspects of these ones are stopping you?

Comment: Take a look at this [Skellam distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution).

Comment: Will $X_1-X_2$ be a Markov process at all? I'm not sure whether that's the case. If $X_1-X_2$ is not a Markov process, the generator is not well-defined.